# IIS7 App Pool stops for inactivity, but doesn't restart when page is requested

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis

We recently moved our webserver from one hosting collocation to another and everything seemed to come online nicely. Once I got back home, I got a call from a customer saying that their site had gone back down. Checked the server and it was still alive and kickin', only their site was unavailable. I logged in and checked the Event Viewer and found this error with no other messages

```
    A worker process with process id of '2900' serving application pool 'Professional Education Services' was shutdown due to inactivity.  
    Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  
    A new worker process will be started when needed.
```

OK, no big deal right? Once it's needed it should spool back up, right? Well, I thought so, but it's not. Any ideas? Is there any configuration that may have to be updated from the move. Our IP addresses all changed and I configured the host headers and DNS records, is there something in IIS that I'm missing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what was happening was caused by a corrupted application pool.

Once I created a new application pool and moved the site into that one and delete the previous, everything worked as we expected.

Comment: That may have been causes by a bad identity user that couldn't run the site, although it's strange that it worked at first and failed later.  Glad you got it working in the end.